# android vm total memory to max memory

Tags: android

I need big amount of memory and I try test it:

```
    long max = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long available = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
        try {
            Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(manager.open("image.png"));
            list.add(btm);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Total ", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
        Log.d("Free ", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
    }

            //dont let vm to clear bitmaps
    for (Bitmap object : list) {
        object.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
    }

    Log.d("Total ", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
    Log.d("Free ", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
```

I tested this and it throw OutOfMemory (vm not let to allocate more than 5 mb for this application)

on the device (for example Kindle Fire) max = 64 mb , total = 5mb free 2.3 mb  and if I use more then 5 mb (total memory) vm force close.
Is it possible to increase vm heap size to MaxMemory  (64)?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to go Android Virtual Device Manager(AVD manager) and click Edit there you can change the memory size, thus you can make spaces available to run your application.

Comment: I am writing application that will be work on the all device for what I need Emulator? 0.o

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you are creating so many bitmaps which you are not recycling in your for loop. One thing for sure is Android is designed in such a way that the memory can be handled precisely. Since you are using list of bitmap it doesn't mean that you will need huge memory. You can recycle your bitmaps or create scaled bitmaps which will reduce the heap memory thus reducing your chances of force close.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
        try {
            Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(manager.open("image.png"));
            list.add(btm);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Total ", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
        Log.d("Free ", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
    }
```

Inside the for loop add, `btm.recycle();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
            try {
                Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(manager.open("image.png"));
                list.add(btm);
               btm.recycle();
               btm=null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Total ", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
            Log.d("Free ", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024f / 1024f + "");
        }
```

This is just a suggestion of you can use the memory in a optimized way.

And to answer your question **need big amount of memory** android doesn't allow it. And the available memory for each app varies from device to device. It would be better if you try my suggestion here.

Comment: no, image.png is 30 kb only and 34x30 kb is only 7 mb and why VM  not let me to allocate 7mb? maxmemory is 64 mb...

Comment: but it is limited for each app at run time. u r talking abt total memory which maybe 64. I f andorid requires memory it will kill background applications which might be running.